# I'm having trouble converting this MySQL query into PHP with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email
FROM users U, friends F
WHERE
CASE

WHEN F.friend_one = '$user_id'
THEN F.friend_two = U.user_id
WHEN F.friend_two= '$user_id'
THEN F.friend_one= U.user_id
END

AND 
F.status='1';
```

$sql = "SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email" .
      "  FROM users U, friends F" .
      " WHERE " .
      "  CASE " .
      "  WHEN F.friend_one = $friend_one" . 
      "  THEN F.friend_two = U.user_id" . 
      "  WHEN F.friend_two= '*' " .
      "  THEN F.friend_one= U.user_id" .
      "   END " .
      "   AND F.status = " . $one;
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

I figured it out myself thanks for all that tried to help.

Comment: And where is the PHP code?

Comment: what is the datatype of `F.status`??

Comment: *"I'm having trouble converting this MySQL query into PHP with PDO"* - Read the manual http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: this is how i usually SELECT , FROM , WHERE QUERIES ..

Comment: try
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = " . $user_id;
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
 require_once('../scripts/show_error.php'. $user_id);
 exit();

Comment: I have no idea how to add all the other stuff /// CASE . WHEN AND WHERE

Comment: Do  you have a database connection set up already?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email\n"
    . "FROM users U, friends F\n"
    . "WHERE\n"
    . "CASE\n"
    . "\n"
    . "WHEN F.friend_one = \'105\'\n"
    . "THEN F.friend_two = U.user_id\n"
    . "WHEN F.friend_two= \'*\'\n"
    . "THEN F.friend_one= U.user_id\n"
    . "END\n"
    . "\n"
    . "AND \n"
    . "F.status=\'1\'";

Comment: yeah database connection is set

Comment: that code above dosen't work throws me to the catch statement to the error page

Comment: Well just echo the exception message. PDO will tell you what is wrong with it..

Comment: DataBase Error: The user could not be added.
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'105\' THEN F.friend_two = U.user_id WHEN F.friend_two= \'*\' THEN F.friend_one' at line 6

Comment: You have entirely unnecessary backslashes in your query...

Comment: No didn't.......work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email" .
  "  FROM users U, friends F" .
  " WHERE " .
  "  CASE " .
  "  WHEN F.friend_one = $friend_one" . 
  "  THEN F.friend_two = U.user_id" . 
  "  WHEN F.friend_two= '*' " .
  "  THEN F.friend_one= U.user_id" .
  "   END " .
  "   AND F.status = " . $one;
```

$result = $pdo->query($sql);